# Is there some way to increase the thickness of the outline around selected objects?

Tags: interface, customization

I'm visually handicapped, and am finding it very difficult sometimes to see which object, of many, in a scene is the "selected" one as The line/halo surrounding it is very thin.

Is there a setting in the preferences that controls this, or perhaps a third-party plug-in?

Answer (score 17):

You do this by changing the *Outline Width* value in your user preferences under the *Themes* tab. The maximum value is `5` so if this is still hard to see, you can try changing the color (look for the value *Active Color* in the same panel) or try adjusting the color of your viewport to make it more prominent.

---

In Blender v3.0 *Outline Width* can be found under *Themes* -> *3D Viewport*

[image]